# Unable to find option to update git in Azure Web App?

Tags: git, azure, azure-web-app-service, kudu

How to update git version to latest in Azure Web app or Kudu build?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly: the version of Git that's running on your web app is managed by Azure.

Answer (score 0):

*Check the current git version:*

```bash
git --version
```

To update git version, use below command in `Azure web app -> Development tools -> console`.

```bash
git update-git-for-windows -y
```

***It will download to the latest version.***

[image]

Comment: Upon following above instruction get output screen as given above but it didn't updated git version, was it same case for you Jahnavi?